# How do I configure ctags to work with Vim?

Tags: vim, ctags

When I use Vim to navigate the source codes such as Linux and Android, if I want to know a function or variable's definition, I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to jump. However, if there is more than one definition, this is not ideal since because ctags jumps to the first one directly. If ctags worked like cscope, that would be perfect!

My question is how to configure ctags to make it works like cscope?

Another question is how to search for a symbol which appears in the whole project, like cscope's `cscope find s XXX`?

Last question is how to set the variable `path` in Vim to make commands like <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> work properly? I set it like `$PWD/**/include`, the search speed is horrible as it searches a lot of directory that shouldn't be searched.

Comment: There are too many different questions here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is how to configure ctags to make it works like cscope?

```
:nmap <c-]> g]
```

That may help a bit.

Also checkout the following help pages:

```
:help include-search
:help 'wildignore'
```